# 3D mesh thick hollow cone/cylinder OBJ creation with Python

Tags: python, mesh, trimesh

I am using Python and would like to create an OBJ file for a hollow partial cone (the cap is cut) on top of a hollow cylinder which both have a constant thickness.

The important requirement is that the object does not only consist of two 2D meshed concentric shapes, but rather a fully 3D meshed object, with all normals pointing outward (meaning, inward for inner cone surface, outward for outer cone surface).

Is there any module in Python that would allow me to achieve that? I tried with trimesh, but unfortunately upon export into an OBJ file, there is no 3D mesh. It is necessary to use Python only and not to use external tools.

Thank you!